# Can we create a virtual table with temporary information from the select command (not other tables)?

Tags: mysql, delphi, zeos

I need to fill up a TDBLookupComboBox with the options for a ENUM column:

```
MOD_MARKETING       ENUM('NENHUMA','CONSULTAR','CADASTRAR','GERENCIAR')
```

But I do not want to create a new table in the database project just for that.
I don't want to use assistant tables. Only tables with the user content.

So, how may I create a temporary virtual table every time I open my application and put those four rows without touch the database structure on the server?

Comment: Are you aware of the [TClientDataset](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet) component? you can use this component to create in memory tables.

Comment: Do you want to read metadata which are stored in MySQL?

Comment: @RRUZ, I did not test TClientDataset but I know that it uses metadata. I will try it.

Comment: @Devart, if you mean stored by 'the options on a ENUM field' then yes, but only if I could convert it to rows, virtually.

Comment: Firebird has GlobalTemporaryTables that might be used for it. There are a lof on in-memory datasets and even SQL databases. ClientDataset, rx/JVCL MEmoryDS, NexusDB SQL in-memory database and a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a component called VirtualTable by DevArt.

It does exactly what I needed.

http://www.devart.com/vtable/